# Gitlab CI DinD Can a child container connect to service running in parent container?

Tags: docker, cypress, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to run E2E test in Gitlab CI.

The service is running in docker container at port localhost:3000 <-- This is parent container

Inside that container, I run docker run command for Cypress test by having cypress_baseUrl=http://localhost:3000 so that it can run test against the service hosts in parent container <-- This is child container

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
e2e_test:
  stage: e2e
  extends: .sbt_base
  services:
    - name: "$HARBOR_REGISTRY/$DIND_IMAGE"
      alias: docker
  variables:
    no_proxy: "${no_proxy}"
    NO_PROXY: "${NO_PROXY}"
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    DIND_IMAGE: "library/docker:19.03.14-dind"
    TRUST_STORE_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/integration/resources/trustStore.jks"
    KEYSTORE_PATH: "/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
  tags:
    - m1.xlarge
  before_script:
    - sed -i 's/localhost:/docker:/' integration/dbo/GitRepoIT.scala conf/local.conf conf/application.conf
    - export TRUST_STORE_PASS=`echo $TRUST_STORE_PASS | base64 -d`
    - export KEYSTORE_PASS=`echo $KEYSTORE_PASS | base64 -d`
    - keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $TRUST_STORE_PATH -destkeystore $KEYSTORE_PATH -srcstorepass $TRUST_STORE_PASS -deststorepass $KEYSTORE_PASS -noprompt
    - keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/integration/resources/it-cacerts -destkeystore $KEYSTORE_PATH -srcstorepass $KEYSTORE_PASS -deststorepass $KEYSTORE_PASS -noprompt
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml build --pull
    - docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
    - sbt "run -Dconfig.resource=local.conf"
    - curl localhost:3000
    - docker run cypress_baseUrl=http://localhost:3000 my.company.io/project-sample/app-cypress:latest yarn cypress:ci
```

Command to run service in parent container is *sbt "run -Dconfig.resource=local.conf"* then I curl to where my application is running which is localhost:3000 and got response back

Next I executed docker run command to create container for Cypress test. However I got this error

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
  > http://localhost:3000
We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.
Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
```

I have a hunch that what I missed is --network when execute docker run command and another one wrong move is my cypress_baseUrl

Please advice.

Comment: Docker doesn't have a notion of "parent" or "child" containers.  If you're launching a container from inside another container, `localhost` will still refer to the current container and not the other container or the host.  Could you potentially [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) the test driver, so it's on the same network as the main service?

Comment: @DavidMaze I can't run the application service in docker container (somehow when running in container, the application cannot start) so I have to live with it this way.